# How do I view effective dns servers?

Tags: networking, dns, troubleshooting

How do I list what dns servers are being searched for things that need to do dns searches?

It doesn't seem like what I have in `resolv.conf` is being used, So i want to troubleshoot and step one of that would be to have the system print out what servers it is using.

Everything I found so far assumes I have network manager installed, but I do not, and so `nmcli` or other such commands would not work.

`Linux linuxtest 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: `resolv.conf` (no "e").  Why do you think it's not being used?

Comment: `man nslookup`?

Comment: @BowlOfRed Typo fixed.

Comment: I'm not 100% I understand what you're asking, but [djbdns](https://cr.yp.to/djbdns.html) has a tool named `dnstrace`.  There are other, similar tools floating around, of varying quality.

Comment: `host` has a flag which shows, what you want.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of tools for troubleshooting DNS.

- **DIG:** IF you just `dig` a name of a webserver then this tools will show you enough details for the simple troubleshooting you have mentioned. Example,

  ```
  arif@arif:~$ dig google.com
  ; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
  ;; global options: +cmd
  ;; Got answer:
  ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 58212
  ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
  ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
  ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
  ;; QUESTION SECTION:
  ;google.com.            IN  A

  ;; ANSWER SECTION:
  google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.200.100
  google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.200.102
  google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.200.139
  google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.200.138
  google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.200.101
  google.com.     299 IN  A   74.125.200.113

  ;; Query time: 287 msec
  ;; SERVER: 192.168.97.54#53(192.168.97.54)
  ;; WHEN: Fri Sep 29 03:39:37 EDT 2017
  ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 135
  ```

  Here you can see in the **3rd line from last** that which DNS server you are using to resolve name. In my case it is 192.168.97.54 and as everybode does you are using port 53. In the following example I will show you same thing but but using specific dns server (Dyn-216.146.35.35) and like before you can see that in the **;;SERVER** section.

  ```
  arif@arif:~$ dig @216.146.35.35 linux.org
  ; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @216.146.35.35 linux.org
  ; (1 server found)
  ;; global options: +cmd
  ;; Got answer:
  ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16485
  ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
  ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
  ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1480
  ;; QUESTION SECTION:
  ;linux.org.         IN  A

  ;; ANSWER SECTION:
  linux.org.      300 IN  A   104.28.16.26
  linux.org.      300 IN  A   104.28.17.26

  ;; Query time: 133 msec
  ;; SERVER: 216.146.35.35#53(216.146.35.35)
  ;; WHEN: Fri Sep 29 03:54:56 EDT 2017
  ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 70
  ```
- **NSLOOKUP:** Doing `nslookup` is the simplest answer in your case. Example:

  ```
  arif@arif:~$ nslookup google.com
  Server:     192.168.97.54
  Address:    192.168.97.54#53
  Non-authoritative answer:
  Name:   google.com
  Address: 74.125.200.102
  ```

  Now doing same thing with the specific DNS server,

  ```
  arif@arif:~$ nslookup linux.org 216.146.35.35
  Server:     216.146.35.35
  Address:    216.146.35.35#53
  Non-authoritative answer:
  Name:   linux.org
  Address: 104.28.16.26
  ```

Comment: All of those do not return the list of dns servers it searched, and only return a dns server if they get a result. If they fail to find a result they just specify they couldn't get a result without listing all of the dns servers it attempted

Comment: The magic that is missing here is the '+trace' command-line option to dig.

`dig +trace [host]`